# Please guide upon optimize my.cnf of MariaDB 10.6.14 on Wordpress Woocommerce site

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf, mariadb-10.6

Before post, I read post at [InnoDB tables in an 8GB RAM server: Are these settings optimized?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291262/innodb-tables-in-an-8gb-ram-server-are-these-settings-optimized), but it seems not fully relevant to my case. It would be great if any MariaDB expert could guide me based on my specific server.

If I click around 40 Woocommerce product page at frontend, there Be an issue of Error establishing a database connection at frontend, or mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.

[image]

Or

[image]

The following are my server, database, and my.cnf:

```
Server: 
8 GB / 4 AMD vCPUs / 160 GB Disk / - Ubuntu 22.04 (LTS) x64
```

Database:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.6.14-MariaDB-1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2204-log - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10

du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib/mysql/
8.0K    /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema
1.8G    /var/lib/mysql/mysite_com_AtxdyVmk
600K    /var/lib/mysql/sys
180K    /var/lib/mysql/slow_query_log
11M     /var/lib/mysql/mysql
4.1G    /var/lib/mysql/
```

The my.cnf:

```
# MariaDB database server configuration file.
# Optimized by WordOps 3.16.3
#
# You can copy this file to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = localhost
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_connections     = 100
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 60
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
thread_cache_size        = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 16M
open-files-limit    = 500000
table_open_cache    = 16000
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 0
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
query_cache_type        = 0
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
#log_bin_index      = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
#expire_logs_days   = 10
#max_binlog_size         = 100M
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED
binlog_format = ROW

# slaves
#relay_log      = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
innodb_log_file_size    = 36M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 290M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 72M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 500000
innodb_io_capacity  = 500000
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 64M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completion

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
```

Comment: Your 180k slow query log is filled with queries over 10 seconds? I'd consider reading that file, using a tool like [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) to summarize it, and looking at what is causing them, and if they could be indexed better. Use a second question here for those and include [Analyze format=json](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) output along with `show create table` definations.